# como fazer imagens mudarem de tamanho sem perder qualidade?

Tags: bootstrap

Eu estou a trabalhar neste site em bootstrap http://turismo.adota-me.tk/

Tudo o que queria era que dependendo do formato de ecras as imagens não perdessem qualidade

testei o seguinte

```css
<style>
  
 .img-responsive,
.thumbnail > img,
.thumbnail a > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
 
}
</style>
```

```html
<link href="http://turismo.adota-me.tk/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div  class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
   <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://turismo.adota-me.tk//img/carousel/lisbon.jpg" width="2050" height="673" alt="lisbon">
    </div>
   <div class="item">
       <img src="http://turismo.adota-me.tk//img/carousel/lisbon.jpg" width="2050" height="673" alt="lisbon">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://turismo.adota-me.tk//img/carousel/lisbon.jpg" width="2050" height="673" alt="lisbon">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
  
 </body>
```

O problema prende-se que quando o ecrã deixa de ser horizontal aa imagens começam a deixar os elementos mais finos.

Acho que vou ter de ter 2 ou 3 imagens guardadas no servidor e exibir elas consoante o ecra

Comment: Talvez [isso](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering) ajude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que esta acontecendo na real é que em uma tela menor, digamos 600px você esta explicitamente dizendo que quer ela com o tamanho de 2050px, quase 4 vezes maior que a tela.

Uma saida, mas talvez não a melhor, é definir o `width`da imagem para 100% e remover o `height`, que esta distorcendo, isso vai fazer a imagem ocupar todo o tamanho da tela e manter a proporção.

Outra coisa que percebi tambem é que as imagens estao com uma proporção mais "fina" [essa por exemplo](http://turismo.adota-me.tk//img/carousel/lisbon.jpg) tem 2045x300

```css
<style> .img-responsive,
.thumbnail > img,
.thumbnail a > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  display: block;
}
</style>
```

```html
<link href="http://turismo.adota-me.tk/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://turismo.adota-me.tk//img/carousel/lisbon.jpg" width="100%" alt="lisbon">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://turismo.adota-me.tk//img/carousel/lisbon.jpg" width="100%" alt="lisbon">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://turismo.adota-me.tk//img/carousel/lisbon.jpg" width="100%" alt="lisbon">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
```